# every time i run my text file program i get runfile wdir output

Tags: python, error-handling, pycharm

```
def count():
    f=open("C:\\Users\pbjmc\\Desktop\\New folder\\STORY.TXT","r")
    line=f.read()
    words=line.split()
    count=0
    for w in words:
        for i in range(len(w)):
            if w[i] in ['a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U']:
                count+=1
    print("no. of words w vowel= ",count)
    f.close()
```

i am fairly new to programming and python and seem to get this output everytime i run a file program

```
PyDev console: starting.
Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
runfile('C:/Users/pbjmc/Desktop/New folder/g.py', wdir='C:/Users/pbjmc/Desktop/New folder')
```

could someone help me resolve this issue? i don't think there's an error in my code

Answer (score 1):

I copied all of your code, but adjusted the file name to just `"story.txt"`, and it worked fine. Adjusting the file name will work if `yourprogram.py` file is in the same folder as `story.txt`, because when files are in the same folder or directory you only need the actual file name, in this case, `story.txt`. I believe the longer directory (`"C:\\Users\pbjmc\\Desktop\\New folder\\STORY.TXT"`) is for files in separate folders.

I adjusted the file name and ran the program, calling the function in the IDE shell, and it was fine.

Conclusion: Change the text file directory name to `"story.txt"` or `"STORY.TXT"` (both will work).

Additionally, if the text file is in another place, I suggest making a folder called `story scripts` (or whatever), in the same place/folder as `yourprogram.py`, then chuck `story.txt` in there. Then change (in `yourprogram.py`) the file directory name to `"story scripts/story.txt"`

Hope that makes sense and helps!

Comment: thanks for your reply! unfortunately i've already tried that but it availed no use and i got the same output

Comment: Ah, thats a pain. Perhaps it is the directory? Maybe there should be 'administrator' (or your computer user account, unless "pbjmc" is that) after 'users', or perhaps you have missed a folder name in the directory? Maybe use only single slashes "\".  Worked fine for me so I wonder what the issue is... :(

Comment: I just copied the directory path from the IDLE shell and used that instead. It did come up with an error, so I replaced all of the "\' with "/", and then it worked fine. Maybe thats the problem.

Comment: i tried that too, since i was getting an error on \, i used \\

 
File "C:/Users/pbjmc/Desktop/New folder/g.py", line 2
    f=open("C:\Users\pbjmc\Desktop\New folder\STORY.TXT","r")
          ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: Golly! Kinda weird how it worked fine for me. Maybe completely copy the `g.py` and the `story.txt` contents into new `py` and `txt` files and then put them in a new folder. Other than that, I don't think I am of much use to you, anymore sorry. I hope you get it figured out eventually.

Comment: ah yes, i guess thats the only option left. Thank you for your help !